# include file and get variables, but not content

Tags: php, include

I have a file which gets content from an XML.

```
ob_start();
require_once 'feed.php';

    $title = 'ExampleTitle';

    foreach(Feed('example.url') as $f ) {
        if (strpos($f->title, $title) !== false)
            echo $f->description;
    }

    $output = ob_get_contents();
```

Outputs example:

`Currently 21*C and sunny.`

I have saved the output in a variable using `ob_start();` and `$output = ob_get_contents();`.

I want to use the `$output` and other variables inside another PHP file. but when I include it inside the other PHP using `include ('status.php');`. It outputs the result as well. I only want to access the variables, not the file to output anything.

I am currently using the file that outputs. So I don't want to change it

Hope it`s clear what I meant. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You can assign the variable in session instead, Or redesign your solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign the variables in session, then you can use it in any page that you desire.

i.e. inyour `status.php`

```
<?php
session_start();

#your codes
$output = ob_get_contents();

$_SESSION["output"] = $output; //Then use the session

?>
```

Or if you must include, then you will have to hide the dirt, in a hidden tag.

```
<div style="display:none;">
<?php  include('status.php'); ?>
</div>

<?php echo $output; //here is your variable  ?>
```